# Save all data cliking just on a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have next application:

 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-butterfly-79k1s?file=/Main.js 
There i try to save data clicking just one button - `Main Submit`, but now if i want to save data from `Add field` functionality, i have to save data clicking on `Submit` button, so in this way  i have 2 butons for saving all data.

```js
 <Form
      {...layout}
      name="basic"
      initialValues={{ remember: true }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
    >
      <Form.Item
        label="Username"
        name="username"
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your username!" }]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Demo />
      <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Main Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
```

**How to save all data just clicking on `Main Submit` button?**

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a function that saves data from dynamic columns using the "Submit" button then just call "submitSave" function after Main Submit saving is done.

I would suggest having a pattern in naming the fields (classes or ids of something else) so that you can fetch all the columns and data in one query and save using one function only.

`Eg:  document.querySelectorAll("[class^=_field]")`

```
<mainSubmitButton onClick="mainSubmitSave()"></mainSubmitButton>

<submitButton class="fieldSave" onClick="anotherSave()"></submitButton>

Method One: mainSubmitSave(){
//finish the saving part
anotherSave();
}

Method two: mainSubmitSave(){
//finish the saving part
document.getElementById('fieldSave').click();
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: how to call a function do next: when i click on main save to click in the same time and inner save button?

Comment: You can trigger a click event or call the function that is called by the "submit" button after the "mainSubmit" button has finished saving.

Comment: I have added an example. I have a feeling you are looking for something else. is it?

Comment: how to use this for my example? because i can' get data from all fields. Could you help?

Comment: I suggest you try the above methods for a simple save action first. Getting data from all fields requires a lot of explanation, but it's very easy(I have already give a hint in the answer, have a pattern in class names and fetch values based on that pattern).